# Macro visibility in CubeMx&Atollic bare project

Tags: stm32, cubemx, truestudio

I've created a simple CubeMx project from scratch and opened it up on Atollic TrueStudio. Of course, its compilation gets out successfully. I've been looking around in project's directories and files to better understand the bare structure upon constructing new projects.

I currently use a STM32 board equipped with a CortexM4 CPU and I'm programming in *C* with a GCC compiler. In the project, I've found a header file called *core_cm4.h* that is reach of macros declaration, i.e. *#define* statements. Here is where the odd thing comes up: when I try to use these macros within the *main.c* file (and in any other new file), they are all available and recognized but the following ones:

```
#elif defined ( __GNUC__ )
   #define __ASM            __asm          /*!< asm keyword for GNU Compiler */
   #define __INLINE         inline         /*!< inline keyword for GNU Compiler */
   #define __STATIC_INLINE  static inline
```

The `__GNUC__` symbol is defined and the compiler does not report any warnings or errors. However the IDE does not offer these macros in the drop-down menù and signal the word as a *syntax error*.

I tried to move the declaration somewhere else within the *core_cm4.h* file unsuccessfully. Do I overlook something relevant?

Comment: Your problem could be the "pre" parser from the Atollic Studio / Eclipse.
Have you tried to compile your project even if it is marked as syntax error?

Comment: Yes I tried to and the compilation is successful. Other projects not generated by CubeMX which use the same *core_cm4.h* file retrieve the macros correctly. So maybe is a bad configuration of Atollic projects generated from CubeMX which cause the defect.

Answer (score 0):

You said the `__GNU__` symbol is defined, but the `#elif` is checking against `__GNUC__`, which is not the same thing. Is that a typo on your part?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, yes it was a typo, thank you! However I think it's a SW bug because the cubeMX output project (and its files) is absolutely virgin.

Answer (score 0):

According to your answer, that the project compiles successfully:

Please try to "refresh all files" and afterwards "rebuild" the index.

(You could find this commands by right clicking on the project name in the project explorer)
[image]